# Guard says user is undefined in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

```js
@UseGuards(JwtAccessTokenAuthGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
@SetMetadata('roles', Role.ADMIN)
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
@Post('/add/card')
addCard(@Body() addCardDto: AddCardDto) {
  return this.storeService.addCard(addCardDto);
}
```

This is the RoleGuard

```js
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
  const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
  if (!roles) {
    return true;
  }
  const user = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
  return this.matchRoles(roles, user.user_type);
}
```

In this, the  request object has user in the body or inside the function `addCard` but not in the `RoleGuard`. Their it says undefined. Why so? In the `JwtAccessTokenGuard` I returned the user property.

I want to check it inside the Guard and not in function. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using two of the same decorators, the order, if I recall, is the lowest decorator in the code first, then the highest one. In this case, why not just merge the two `@UseGuards()` to be a single decorator like `@UseGuards(JwtAccessTokenAuthGuard, RolesGuard)` so that you're certain of what order the guards will be ran in [as described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#guards)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the user in the guard by this method:

```js
const user = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
```

You should return the user object in the local strategy. That attaches the `user` object to the `request` object. The body has nothing to do with the `user` object. So, your local.strategy.ts should be something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({ usernameField: 'email' });
  }

  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

For more info, see [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication).

Comment: I did this in my JwtAuthGuard